Sorting by date on a master spreadsheet with data imported from other spreadsheets
I have 4 spreadsheets importing data from cells A2:V, each spreadsheet auto sorts on edit by date (column 17), but when I ask the master sheet to auto sort by column 17, it sorts them by date but also by each spreadsheet for instance spreadsheet 1 is sorted first with spreadsheet 2 underneath, and so on. I need the master to ignore the source when sorting. I assume this has to do with my formula in A2 of the master sheet. How can I fix this?
Formula in A2
={filter(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet1 link", "A2:V"), LEN(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet1 link", A2:A))>0);filter(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet2 link", "A2:V"), LEN(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet2 link", A2:A))>0);filter(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet3 link", "A2:V"), LEN(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet3 link", A2:A))>0);filter(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet4 link", "A2:V"), LEN(IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet4 link", A2:A))>0)}

You can filter and sort the data like this:
=let( 
  rangeA1, "A2:V", 
  data, vstack( 
    importrange("spreadsheet1 link", rangeA1), 
    importrange("spreadsheet2 link", rangeA1), 
    importrange("spreadsheet3 link", rangeA1), 
    importrange("spreadsheet4 link", rangeA1) 
  ), 
  sort(filter(data, len(choosecols(data, 1))), 17, 1) 
)

See See
let(),
vstack(),
choosecols(),
filter()
and
sort().
